# What is the correct way to use Compiled function in Table and Plot without slow down?

Tags: compile

On V 9.01 on windows 7, all 64 bit.

I am sure I am missing something simple here, but I used all the tricks of the trade that I know about, and read docs, and do not see anything that helps.

Here is a compiled function made to speed up some computation.

When this function is put inside `Plot` or `Table` it resort back to being slow at the speed of the original uncompiled function speed.

Using `Evaluate` gives an error.

Here is a MWE (This function takes about one minute to evaluate and compile, sorry that is what I am using, but it is only one line, and takes one minute to compile)

```
ClearAll[f, g, g0, x, b, a];
f = Function[{##} /. {x_, b_, a_} :>Piecewise[{{Exp[-b*(-Log[x])^a], 0. < x <= 1.}}]];
g = InverseFunction[f, 1, 3];
g0 = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {a, _Integer}, {b, _Integer}}, g[x, a, b]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Timing[g0[.1, 3, 2]]
(* {0.156001, 0.416409} *)
```

and

```
Timing[g0[#, 3, 2] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is fast now. Uncompiled version takes more than 60 seconds for each one computation.

But when in a table, it becomes slow again, using the original version? or for some other reason

```
Table[Timing[g0[x, 3, 2]], {x, 0, .1, .1}]
(* {{61.308393, 0.00258519}, {61.323993, 0.416409}} *)
```

`Evaluate` gives error and still slow

```
Table[Evaluate[g0[x, 3, 2]], {x, 0, .1, .1}]
(*CompiledFunction::cfsa: "Argument x at position 1 should be a 
"machine-size real number " *)
```

Direct use of Table is too slow, same as above.

```
Table[g0[x, 3, 2], {x, 0, .1, .1}]
```

Same issue with `Plot`. Can't use `Evaluate` and if I do not, it is slow. Using `Compiled-False` did not help (since `g0` is already compiled), it is still slow

```
Plot[g0[x, 3, 2], {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {Compiled -> False}]; (*slow*)
Plot[g0[x, 3, 2], {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {Compiled -> False}, Evaluated -> False]; 
Plot[g0[x, 3, 2], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> False]; (*slow*)
```

**How can one use Compiled function in `Table` and `Plot` without it being slow?**

Is it one of those `HoldRest`, `HoldFirst` issues or I am missing something more basic here?

Comment: It doesn't get compiled in version 8.0.4, `CompilePrint[g0]` has `MainEvaluate[ Hold[g][ R0, I0, I1]]` and `First@Timing[g0[#, 3, 2] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1]]` gives 0.16, same as when using `g` directly. EDIT: Ran it again, now the timing was very slow...

Comment: As a workaround you could define the inverse as: `g1[v_?NumericQ, b_Integer, a_Integer] := 
 Block[{x}, x /. FindRoot[f[x, b, a] == v, {x, .5}]]` which takes ~2s to plot, if you plan to use it often you could also interpolate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that in this instance, Compile is a red-herring.  There is, however, something very strange going on.

Let's define your functions but do not use compilation.  Start a shiny new kernel and do

```
ClearAll[f, g, g0, x, b, a];
f = Function[{##} /. {x_, b_, a_} :> 
     Piecewise[{{Exp[-b*(-Log[x])^a], 0. < x <= 1.}}]];
g = InverseFunction[f, 1, 3];
```

This function, g, is nice and fast as it is:

```
In[7]:= AbsoluteTiming[g[#, 3, 2] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1]]

Out[7]= {0.166521, {0.00258519, 0.416409, 0.480731, 0.53073, 0.575419,
   0.618365, 0.661898, 0.708357, 0.761299, 0.829109, 1.}}
```

Let's try the same thing in a Table.

```
In[8]:= AbsoluteTiming[Table[g[x, 3, 2], {x, 0, 1, 0.1}]]

Out[8]= {615.637676, {0.00258519, 0.416409, 0.480731, 0.53073, 
  0.575419, 0.618365, 0.661898, 0.708357, 0.761299, 0.829109, 1.}}
```

Yikes! 3697 times slower!  Best go back to using a Map then:

```
In[9]:= AbsoluteTiming[g[#, 3, 2] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1]]

Out[9]= {56.093623, {0.00258519, 0.416409, 0.480731, 0.53073, 
  0.575419, 0.618365, 0.661898, 0.708357, 0.761299, 0.829109, 1.}}
```

Last time I evaluated this exact expression, it took 0.166 seconds.  Now, it takes 56.1 seconds.  It looks like Table broke the g function!

If you re-evaluate the definition of g:

```
ClearAll[f, g, g0, x, b, a];
f = Function[{##} /. {x_, b_, a_} :> 
     Piecewise[{{Exp[-b*(-Log[x])^a], 0. < x <= 1.}}]];
g = InverseFunction[f, 1, 3];
```

you get fast Mapping of g again:

```
In[17]:= AbsoluteTiming[g[#, 3, 2] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1]]

Out[17]= {0.166521, {0.00258519, 0.416409, 0.480731, 0.53073, 0.575419,
   0.618365, 0.661898, 0.708357, 0.761299, 0.829109, 1.}}
```

OK, so trying to make a Table of g seems to break g.  It get's worse though.  Restart the kernel and run  the following

```
In[1]:= ClearAll[f, g, g0, x, b, a];
f = Function[{##} /. {x_, b_, a_} :> 
     Piecewise[{{Exp[-b*(-Log[x])^a], 0. < x <= 1.}}]];
g = InverseFunction[f, 1, 3];

In[4]:= AbsoluteTiming[g[#, 3, 2] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1]]

Out[4]= {0.158020, {0.00258519, 0.416409, 0.480731, 0.53073, 0.575419,
   0.618365, 0.661898, 0.708357, 0.761299, 0.829109, 1.}}

In[5]:= Table[x, {x, 1, 2, 1}]

Out[5]= {1, 2}

In[6]:= AbsoluteTiming[g[#, 3, 2] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1]]

Out[6]= {56.014613, {0.00258519, 0.416409, 0.480731, 0.53073, 
  0.575419, 0.618365, 0.661898, 0.708357, 0.761299, 0.829109, 1.}}
```

Simply executing Table in between two calls to a Map over g, slows down the Map by a factor of 350 or so!

**EDIT:**

For this issue, slowness in Table appears to be related to choice of variable.  If you avoid the variables used in the definition of f, life is better.  Again, from a clean kernel:

```
In[1]:= ClearAll[f, g, g0, x, b, a];
f = Function[{##} /. {x_, b_, a_} :> 
     Piecewise[{{Exp[-b*(-Log[x])^a], 0. < x <= 1.}}]];
g = InverseFunction[f, 1, 3];
Table[g[z, 3, 2], {z, 0, 1, 0.1}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[4]= {0.161521, {0.00258519, 0.416409, 0.480731, 0.53073, 0.575419,
   0.618365, 0.661898, 0.708357, 0.761299, 0.829109, 1.}}
```

Plotting over z is also OK.

```
Plot[g[z, 3, 2], {z, 0, 1}]
```

The above takes a couple of seconds on my machine.

**EDIT 2**

Redefining your function so that it uses unnamed slots appears to be the long term fix here.

```
In[6]:= f = 
  Function[Piecewise[{{Exp[-#2*(-Log[#1])^#3], 0. < #1 <= 1.}}]];
g = InverseFunction[f, 1, 3];

In[13]:= AbsoluteTiming[g[#, 3, 2] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1]]

Out[13]= {0.115015, {0.00258519, 0.416409, 0.480731, 0.53073, 
  0.575419, 0.618365, 0.661898, 0.708357, 0.761299, 0.829109, 1.}}

In[14]:= AbsoluteTiming[Table[g[x, 3, 2], {x, 0, 1, .1}]]

Out[14]= {0.127016, {0.00258519, 0.416409, 0.480731, 0.53073, 
  0.575419, 0.618365, 0.661898, 0.708357, 0.761299, 0.829109, 1.}}
```